# Unable to add a file to gitignore in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I want to add a file named Credentials to .gitignore, so here's how I did, I added the following line to .gitignore file which is in app directory:

`/src/main/java/my/package/name/utils/Credentials.java`

But it still shows up in git status.

Comment: did you `git add .gitignore` and `git commit` ?

Comment: Did you push this file in the remote repo?

Comment: @mkrufky Yes, I executed `git add .`. There's no need to commit to see an updated git status. Staging area should update after `git add`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti no I didn't.

Comment: @mkrufky But the staging area will be empty after a commit. How do I verify in that case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: @mkrufky _changes to .gitignore dont take effect until you commit them_ - that's wrong, changes to `.gitignore` take effect immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting `man gitignore` :

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git
>   should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected

If the file that you're looking to have ignored by git is already a file being tracked, you'll have to `git rm --cached` it first.

For more info: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore